# Making circular label in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working on d3js charts and have made the cicular progress(the white arc that changes value smoothly).I haven't figure out how to make the label that changes according to the value of the arc.For example in the figure if the value of arc is more than 300 , the labels should update automatically.

[image: circular svg labels].

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Here is the link of my gist: [link]https://gist.github.com/deepakbhattarai/8667775

Comment: So the basic methodology for updating the positions of the labels is the same as for the arcs. [This tutorial](http://blog.stephenboak.com/2011/08/07/easy-as-a-pie.html) can help you with that.

Comment: I have done the same thing with the labels(selecting, and appending data).i have used setInterval method to randomly change the value of the graph. the problem is that arc gets updated but the labels keep on appending. where am i going wrong. i have edited my gist please if you have time suggest what is going wrong

Comment: It looks like you're always appending labels and not using data to compute a join.

Comment: but i have used data to compute a join: svg.selectAll("circle.dots")                
            .style("fill",this.labels[0].pointColor)
            .style("stroke","none")       
            .data(this.dotLabelSettings)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")

Comment: That's for the circles and not for the text elements, no? You need to do the same thing for the text elements.

Comment: these are repeated too. the arc is called every second but it gets updated but the circles are appended. if the problem with circles is solved then it will be same for text

Comment: What I mean is that you're binding data to the circles (using `.data()`) and you don't seem to do the same thing for the text elements.

Comment: i have used `.data()` with circles but it doesn't work too. i have not done anything for text. even the circles are appending

Comment: Could you post a complete example of this please?

Comment: [link]https://gist.github.com/deepakbhattarai/8689275 i have added another gist that uses my graph class

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your code correctly, but are you looking for something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8689540)?

Comment: Great, I'll post this as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost there. To make it work, you basically need two changes. First, the circles and outer labels don't need to be redrawn on update, as they don't change. So I've moved the function call that does that out of the update function. Similarly, you don't need to append a new `text` element in the center of the circle to show the current progress, but just update the existing one.

Complete example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8689540).

Comment: i am having another problem now. what i tried is included the graph in three places in the same page.since i have selected the paths with class selector it changes the value of all. what i want is unique change for each graph. when i used the id selector it doesn't even show. what should i do? i have updated my gist if you have time please look at it. [link]https://gist.github.com/deepakbhattarai

Comment: You could assign different classes for the different graphs.

Comment: i have used id for each svg. but it is not working. do i have to use class or id is ok?

Comment: but it is not working. i have selected arc by `svg.selectAll(g.arc > path)` where svg is the selection of the one svg element what is happening i can't figure out. i have read a lot about selection on d3js but i cannot find where am i going wrong

Comment: Have you tried selecting it explicitly by ID/class, i.e. using `d3.selectAll()` instead of relying on `svg` being what you think it is?

Comment: i have tried that too. i have gave each arc a specific id. and selected with `d3.selectAll` but only the second graph get updated clumsly and the first graph does nothing.neither the progress value changes nor the arc

Comment: and yeah i have inspected the code and it shows only the second graph is being selected. i have consoled the selection and each second only the second graph selection is shown

Comment: here is the index file and progress.js file [link]gist.github.com/deepakbhattarai. i think the second object is overriding the first one

Comment: Well, it looks like your function isn't encapsulated properly. Looks like it wouldn't be a particularly quick change as you would need to check everything quite carefully.

Comment: okay. thank you for your valuable suggestions. i will check everthing again.